# From iPhone 4 to iPhone 5 - UIMageView

Tags: ios, xcode, imageview

I am working on my existing app to customize the screen to make compatible to iPhone 5 screen.
However as you could see in the following figures, my imageview is not properly placed. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated! unlockView represent the arrow. lockViewOutlet image represent the outer of the arrow image.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    float screenSizeHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if(screenSizeHeight==568)
    {
        [lockViewOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548)];
        [unlockImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 500, 68, 43)];
        [unlockText setFrame:CGRectMake(105, 500, 182,43)];

    }
    if(screenSizeHeight==480)
    {
        [lockViewOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
        [unlockImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 411, 68, 43)];
        [unlockText setFrame:CGRectMake(105, 411, 182,43)];

 }
}
```

iPhone 5 screenshot[image]
iphone 4 screenshot[image]

Comment: with this kind of a `slide to unlock` view. Apple will reject your app for sure.

Comment: My app is already on appstore. They did not reject it before.

Comment: if it has the sliding ability with this kind of a unlock controller, Apple will reject your app.

Comment: yes, it is exactly same what apple has.

Comment: if you search totalMobility on appstore, you would see the current version of my app.

Comment: One of my apps got rejected because of this controller.

Comment: anyway, what is the variable name of your slider-view's background view ?

Comment: let's focus on my question please rather to think reject! any help would be appreciated!

Comment: lockViewOutlet is my background view, that includes everything except arrow and text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29572/discussion-between-thilina-hewagama-and-casillas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ok I got you,

The problem is with your image view **lockViewOutlet**.

in your code : `[lockViewOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548)];`

You try to resize your background imageView. **Resizing only the imageView** does not solve your problem. Real problem is with the size of **lockViewOutlet.image**.

Best way is design a new image with the size 320, 568. Then set the image for iphone 5 after resizing your imageview.

```
if(screenSizeHeight==568)
    {
        [lockViewOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 548)];

        [lockViewOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhone5LockNackground.png"]];

        [unlockImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 500, 68, 43)];
        [unlockText setFrame:CGRectMake(105, 500, 182,43)];

    }
```